# can't get the name of the button clicked using jQuery Popconfirm plugin

Tags: java, javascript, php, jquery, forms

So I decided to use this plugin 
https://github.com/Ifnot/PopConfirm
as it was recommended as a good confirm button. I have it set up and all working well, except for one thing.

I validate all my forms in PHP using the name of the button clicked since I have several buttons such as save, cancel, delete. Therefore when a form is submitted in PHP the POST variables available to me are these below and I can validate the button using

```
PHP e.g. 
Array ( [supplier] => "david" [customer] => "new buy" [save] => )

Validate Using
if(isset($_POST['save'])){}
```

But when I use the popconfirm plugin, and since it uses the .submit() to submit the form, on form submission I only get the values of the input box but not the name of the button

```
Using popconfirm to submit the form, I end up with
Array ( [supplier] => "david" [customer] => "new buy" )
```

Since the $_POST['save'] is missing when using popconfirm, I therefore can not validate which button was pressed in PHP as it is not passed on.

I can see the plugin uses

```
form.submit();
```

to submit the form, but what I can not figure out is why is the name of the button not also being posted like how PHP does it or how to get the submit function to also pass on the button name variable

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form using jQuery (which PopConfirm uses), buttons' names and values are not passed with other form data (and I don't know why exactly).
If you see the source of jquery.popconfirm.js you can search for the part that handles buttons by searching for this line of comment:

> ```
>     // If the button is a submit one
> ```

You'll find the part that handles buttons. Add this lines of code right before **form.submit();**

```
btnName = typeof(self.attr('name')) === 'undefined' ? '' : self.attr('name');
btnVal = typeof(self.attr('value')) === 'undefined' ? '' : self.val();
form.append('<input type="hidden" name="' + btnName + '" value="' + btnVal + '" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Now this behaviour is fixed with the lastest version v0.4.5 just drafted.